# Web service in Asp 1.1 not working on http://localhost/ but working from Visual Studio http://localhost:14475/

Tags: web-services, localhost

I need to consume a 3rd party web service. My environment: Asp 1.1, IIS 5.1, IE 7+ and behind a proxy server. I am facing a problem with authentication.

Step 1: I have successfully added the web service - by providing my authentication details for our proxy server.

Step 2: code used to consume the service

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("PROXY SERVER URI:PORT/", true);
proxyObject.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
myObj.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
myObj.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

Step 3: Response I got: "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."
Step 4: I changed code in Credentials to:

```
proxyObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UID", "PASSWORD");
```

Step 5: Result: Proper result.

I also found this: even though I need to work in 1.1, but when I tried to use in 2.0:
Step 1: Code used:

```
myObj.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
myObj.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
myObj.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Step 2: Its working fine as `http://localhost:14475/TransUnion_VS2008/HostWS_FW.asmx?op=TURequest` with a port number when I run from VS2008

Step 3: But the same code is not working as `http://localhost/TU_HostWS/Service.asmx`, when I run from IIS. It threw below error message:

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at TU_Prod.CreditReport.ProcessRequestXMLV2(TUCANREL4 TUCANREL4, REL4Report& REL4Report) at Service.TURequest()

Step 4. It is working from IIS `http://localhost/TU_HostWS/Service.asmx` only when I change the code and provide my authentication details as:

```
proxyObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UID", "PASSWORD");
```

Can you please help me in this? I tried with IIS “not set to Windows, BASIC or Digest, but only as Anonymous” But no luck. Please help..

Comment: I have a similar issue, how did you solved this ?